# jList Custom no se aplica formato

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito una lista personalizada que tenga 2 labels, uno para texto, alineado a la izquierda de la lista y otro que sea un numero alineado a la derecha, este último tiene que ser rojo si es negativo.
Ejemplo (\r representa rojo):

```
Item 1                                                                                    123
Item 2                                                                                  \r-12\r
```

Estoy teniendo varios problemas, el primero es que no logro alinear texto y numeros independientemente, y cuando el numero es negativo, todo el item se vuelve rojo, no unicamente el numero que es lo que intento:
[image: Ejemplo de ejecucion para mostrar problema]

Codigo:

```java
public class CustomList<T> extends JList<T> {

    public CustomList(List<T> data) {
        DefaultListModel<T> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for (T item : data) {
            model.addElement(item);
        }
        setModel(model);

        setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
    }

    private class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            if (value instanceof Item) {
                Item item = (Item) value;
                String text = item.getText();
                int number = item.getNumber();

                String formattedText = String.format("%-10s %10d", text, number);
                label.setText(formattedText);

                label.setForeground(number < 0 ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
            }

            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Item {

    private String text;
    private int number;

    public Item(String text, int number) {
        this.text = text;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text + " - " + number;
    }
}
```

```java
private void initList() {
    listData.add(new Item("Item 1", -1000));
    listData.add(new Item("Item 2", 2040));
    listData.add(new Item("Item 3", -50));
    listData.add(new Item("Item 4", 190));
    listData.add(new Item("Item 5", 2280));

    CustomList<Item> customList = new CustomList<>(listData);

    spList = new JScrollPane(customList);
    spMain.setLeftComponent(spList);
}
```

Comment: Para la alineación tendrías que usar una fuente [monoespaciada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_letra_monoespaciado); aunque podría ser mas fácil con un JTable.

Comment: Pero con una fuente monoespaciada dependería mucho de la longitud del texto que tenga no? Los numeros no estarían perfectamente alineados a la derecha. Y creo que te pillo con lo del jTable, tu dices de poner 2 celdas por fila, en una texto y en otra numero no?, no es una mala opcion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu getListCellRendererComponent() está devolviendo un JLabel. Un JLabel solo admite un texto simple y un color (o un icono). No admite un texto "partido" en alineación iquierda y derecha ni dos colores simultáneamente.

Como te ponen en los comentarios, quizás sería más sencillo un JTable con dos columnas. Si prefieres seguir haciéndolo con un JList, puedes hacer que tu método getListCellRendererComponent() devuelva un contenedor con dos JLabel dentro. El primer JLabel sería el texto alineado a la izquierda, el segundo el número alineado a la derecha y de color rojo si es negativo.

Como contenedor ligero apropiado para esto, puedes usar Box. Sería algo como esto

```
Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
box.add(firstJabel);
box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());  // Hace que los label se separen, el primero quedaría a la izquierda, el segundo a la derecha.
box.add(secondLabel);
```

Tendrás un problema adicional. Tu actual llamada a super.getListCellRendererComponent() hace que el JLabel tenga valores y determinados colores según esté seleccionado o no. Tendrás que hacer new de tus JLabel para meterlos en tu Box y tendrás que poner tú los colores de selección y eso. Podrías llamar a super.getListCellRendererComponent() aunque sólo sea para copiar en tus JLabel los colores de fondo, bordes, etc que te devuelve el JLabel de la llamada a super. Así te evitas implementar la lógica.

Se bueno.

Comment: Vale, veo que es bastante más lio hacer una lista personalizada completa con mis necesidades y que además es absurdo si todo se soluciona con un jtable, así que usaré eso. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

desde las primeras versiones de swing se mostraba en su código demo la forma de agregar elementos de formato y personalizar el contenido de los JLabel usando HTML. Esto nos da la ventaja de que como tu CustomCellRenderer usa un JLabel para renderizar podamos darle el formato que queramos con HTML.

Para los espacios normalmente se podría usar un `\t`, pero una vez que estás en el mundo HTML tal vez lo más simple sea usar una entidad `&nbsp;`, quedando el código de tu cell renderer como

```java
public class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private static final String POSITIVE_COLOR = "'5e5e5e'";
    private static final String NEGATIVE_COLOR = "'#ff3e3e'";

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value instanceof Item item) {
            String text = item.getText();
            int number = item.getNumber();

            String fontColor = number < 0 ? NEGATIVE_COLOR : POSITIVE_COLOR;

            String formattedText = String.format("<html>%-10s&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=%s>%10d</font></html>", text, fontColor, number);
            label.setText(formattedText);
        }

        return label;
    }
}
```

Y con esto tu lista se vería así

[image: ejemplo de renderización con el formato deseado]